# Hide XCOPY confirmation of number of files copied

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I've had a look at the switches for XCOPY and can't seem to find one that suppresses the confirmation of the **number of files** that have been copied.

Do you know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you can simply send it to `nul`:

```
xcopy source destination options > nul
```

Comment: As easy as that. Thanks!

Comment: But what if I want the names of the files copied to be displayed (e.g. xcopy /f) but not the final "files copied" message?

Comment: Figured it out, see my answer.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to see messages about **which** files are being copied but suppress the final message about **how many** files were copied, then you can use find:

```
xcopy source destination options|find /v "File(s) copied"
```

This will display all lines of output that don't contain the string "File(s) copied". Use the /F option to xcopy to display full source and destination filenames.

Comment: Confirmed: this solution worked exactly as I needed.  I had a perpetually running CMD file that I wanted to copy files in a source directory tree whenever a source file was updated.  I was using > nul before to suppress too much output, but I wanted to change it to list the filenames whenever a copy occurred.  Changing it to use FIND /V "File(s) copied" was perfect.

Comment: This only works if the system language is set to English. I can be adapted for your language settings, or for a more generic solution something like this could be used: `xcopy src dst opt |findstr "\\"`, but make sure you have a backslash in the source directory (e.g. use .`\src` if you're copying from a local directory).

Answer (score 1):

xcopy doesn't handle non-standard characters (e.g., «׃¿) ... use xxcopy instead:
xxcopy "G:\Files\" /L /S /ZS

/ZS suppresses all the summary reporting and leaves only the filenames.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
xcopy "C:\source_folder\test_file.txt" "C:\destination_folder" /Q > nul
```

`/Q` removes the file name while copying and `>nul` removes the prompt *".. File(s) copied"*

Answer (score 0):

Just use `>nul 2>&1` will supress all the output of the the line.

For example `echo Hello World >nul 2>&1` will have no output.